# Add 1 days to Custom properties in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to get 1 day for Custom properties(redady api).

Custom properties date is `2020-02-09T00:00:00Z`

I want to have plus 1 day `2020-02-10T00:00:00Z`

```
def date1 = context.expand(' $(#TestCase#EndDate) ')
def date2 = date1.plus(1)
```

The result  `2020-02-09T00:00:00Z1`

How its possible to have custom properties date plus 1 day ?

Thanks

Comment: You are manipulating a string (thus doing string concatenation). You should parse that into a date first.

Answer (score 0):

As @ernest_k pointed out, first parse your given date from `String` to `Date`.

```
//define your desired date format
def dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
```

Then parse it to Date

```
def givenDate = Date.parse(dateFormat, yourDate)
```

Finally add `day(s)` to the given date

```
def plusOneDay = Date.parse(dateFormat, givenDate).plus(1)
```

And you can do all the works in a line too -

```
def oneDayPlus = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", yourDate).plus(1)
```

Comment: Thank you , my base date is 2020-02-09T00:00:00Z but after parsing and plus day i have result 2020-01-10T00:00:00Z but its wrong.

Comment: there was a silly mistake at the `dateFormat`. I've updated the answer. You can check now. This should give you the right answer.